# How to write s.source_files?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to upload my first cocoaPod lib , and here when I goes the step:
`pod lib lint`, i always got `- ERROR | file patterns: The`source_files`pattern did not match any file.`

I write s.source_files like this : `s.source_files  = "JXTools/*.{h,m}"`

here is my project :

[image]
[image]

Can any one tell me what's wrong with my s.source_file? and how to fix it?

Comment: `"JXTools/*.{h,m}"` This mean all the .h and .m files inside `JXTools` folder, but your .h and .m files are inside another folder inside `JXTools`, it's not recursive. Try `"JXTools/Objective-C/*.{h,m}"` instead. Or for any "subfolder", use `"JXTools/**/*.{h,m}"` (check the doc: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source_files)

Comment: thanks a log . already fixed it~